# How can I create a ext3 filesystem with content (files/dirs) and pack them in a binary file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3

I would like to create a binary file to be flashed on a SD card. This file should contain a single ext3 partition and should have some files/directories already in it.

How could I do this avoiding using any command which would require root privileges.

Thak you very much!

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/e2fsimage/ or http://genext2fs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you! Using genext2fs did the trick, along with using tune2fs to enable journaling (ext3).

Comment: The only problem I have now is that I need a block size of 4096 instead of 1024. Genext2fs supports only this latter value.

Comment: Well, as far as I know all these programs are built on top of libext2fs, so theoretically they can do anything what mkfs.ext2 does. But certainly some options and switches may be inaccessible in a particular program because its author forget to provide it to a user. I think you may write a message to the author and politely ask for a feature.

Comment: I have managed to solve that too, took the latest sources for genext2fs and built them, now I have all the goodies.

Answer (score 0):

As user3159253 told in his comment I used genext2fs along with tune2fs to enable journaling (ext3). For having a block size > 1024 bytes you must build the latest genext2fs sources, the one provided in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS doesn't offer such options being a bit old.